# Issue while Instantiating SharePoint 2010 method in MSCRM 2011 plug-in

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

This is regarding SharePoint 2010 Integration with MSCRM 2011. 
While creating a record in CRM, trying to create a Custom Document location for that record and a similar folder in sharepoint, So that when user clicks on document link in the entity record it does not prompt user to create folder in Sharpoint (Trying to avoid sharepoint noise for better user experience)

I have implemented through post create asynchronous plug-in. (I did this through console program working fine). Build the plug`enter code here`-in and deployed to CRM.

When creating a record it error out with a message like "An internal server 500 error - Could not load the assembly with public key token etc…blab bla bla…”

But when I am  debugging the plug-in it failed at the first line of command where I am instantiating sharePoint method  Create client context of sharepoint, it says [System.Security.SecurityException]={“That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers”.}

As per google, per this issue it should be having one attribute  “Allow partial users” in assembly info file. As per my understanding, this should be done in because the request goes from CRM plug-in to SharePoint dll. I mean share point dlls are not allowing request from my assembly. How can we change that?

I have referenced Microsoft.SharePoint.client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
What is the alternate to overcome this issue?

Appreciate if some one can help me ..Thanks In advance.

Here is my code for SharePoint

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl)
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
 Cc.Add(new Uri(siteUrl), "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
                clientContext.Credentials = cc;
                clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                SP.List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                ListItemCreationInformation newItem = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                newItem.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
                newItem.FolderUrl = siteUrl + "/" + folderlogicalName;

                if (!relativePath.Equals(string.Empty))
                    newItem.FolderUrl += "/" + relativePath;


                newItem.LeafName = newfolderName; 
                SP.ListItem item = list.AddItem(newItem);
                item.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Where I am passing the siteurl, folderlogicalname,relativepath and new foldername as parameters.

This works fine from my Console application. But when converted to CRM plug-in it gives the above specified issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a similar issue before.

CRM plugins run inside a sandbox, so all assemblies *and* .NET libraries used must allow partial trust callers (since the CRM sandbox runs under partial trust). It works in the console because you are executing the code as a full trust user in that context.

This issue is not necessarily your code, but could be a dependency or a .NET library itself does not allow partial trust callers - in your case it sounds like the Sharepoint library is the culprit (but a stack trace of the error should reveal exactly where the cause is).

Since you don't have access to the source library causing the problem, to overcome the error you will likely have to create a wrapper. However, the problem is the wrapper cannot directly reference the problem library or you will get the same issue. So to get around this, you may have to create a web service which acts as your wrapper and then call the web service in your CRM plugin. This way the full trust code is executed by the web service (which is full trust) and then returns the result to your calling CRM plugin.

Here is [more info on the error](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/302377cf-97bd-4fe9-b7d0-fa7f08152927/systemsecuritysecurityexception-that-assembly-does-not-allow-partially-trusted-callers?forum=crmdevelopment).

Comment: Thanks Jason for your response and detailed explanation. May be I will adopt your idea of implementing Web services. But Still I have one Question. As per my knowledge CRM plug-ins can be registered in Sandbox and Database. I am registering my plug-in in database not in sandbox mode. Would you explain more about this. Another question would be How CRM and SharePoint integrations works without customizations. We cannot every time depend on Web services right for this. Once again appreciate your time.

Comment: If you are on-premise then in addition to registering your plugin as full trust, you would need to register any dependent [Sharepoint] libraries to the GAC on the CRM server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason. This works for me.
I Would like to add additional few points to the answer.
1. I have added the sharepoint dlls to the bin folder of CRM 2011 site.
2. Also deployed the same dlls in the folder whereever Async job is running to make my Async plug-in to work.

Thanks once again for the cooperation